# StoreContrl API for Product/GetCatalog?pageSize=10 API are not giving product listing

Tags: php, api, curl

StoreContrl API for Product/GetCatalog?pageSize=10 API are not giving product listing. When tried to call  Product/GetCatalog?pageSize=10 API it returns always below message:

> {"Message":"Product synchronization has been approved in total_sync status\r\n Use the totalsynchronisation calls instead."}

Please suggest how can I implement it with my code.